# Hibernate exhausted result set

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a table which name is AsyncFcmNotification , this table has partitioned on a timestamp column.
when I want to execute this query.

```
do {
    try (HibernateSession session = SessionManager.openSession()) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        List<AsyncFcmNotification> asyncFcmNotifications = session.createQuery("from AsyncFcmNotification where sent = false")
                .setFirstResult(offset)
                .setMaxResults(count)
                .list();
        updateUnsendNotif(asyncFcmNotifications, session);
        offset += 100;
    }
    logger.info(offset + " notif has updated");
} while (offset < asyncFcmNotificationsCount);
```

asyncFcmNotificationsCount value is 105220;

I get these exceptions

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your stack trace as a text.

Comment: are you getting this error after 1st iteration or whenever you loop start.

Comment: Are you using the Hibernate session concurrently, because that is not supported.